# Error using Express for NodeJS: 'engine' of object #<View> is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm new to nodejs and was wondering if anyone knew how to debug this error:

```
TypeError: Property 'engine' of object #<View> is not a function
```

I've just installed an express instance after a bit of work getting node/npm installed on an ubuntu box. Any ideas? Here's my stack trace:

```
500 TypeError: Property 'engine' of object #<View> is not a function
at View.render (/var/www/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:75:8)
at Function.app.render (/var/www/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:504:10)
at ServerResponse.res.render (/var/www/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:676:7)
at exports.index (/var/www/routes/index.js:7:7)
at callbacks (/var/www/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:165:11)
at param (/var/www/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:139:11)
at pass (/var/www/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:146:5)
at Router._dispatch (/var/www/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:173:5)
at Object.router (/var/www/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
at next (/var/www/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
```

Here's routes/index.js 7:7:

```
res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
```

Comment: What view engine are you trying to use? You may need to configure the callback for it with [`app.engine`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.engine) and possibly use [consolidate.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/consolidate.js) to have a compatible callback to configure.

Comment: show us routes/index.js:7:7, please :)

Comment: I believe the view engine I'm using is jade. I'll have to look into using consolidate...

Updated @rdey =)

Comment: That line looks great, but is not quite enough extra info to answer your question. :) Do you set up jade somewhere? Do you define a views directory, etc? That code would be useful to see, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it figured out. The problem was I didn't have the dependencies properly installed. It worked after I ran this command:

```
cd . && sudo npm install
```

My commands before that to get the app working were referencing the first part of this tutorial:

http://shapeshed.com/creating-a-basic-site-with-node-and-express/

Thanks for the help!

Comment: why are you using sudo?